# check if records are same with previous data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to check two data frames records if they are same if not same then filter out the records and save the records in excel files.

for example if ANA2719 is not available in df2 but available in df then filter out the row and save as xlsx file

vise versa for the same KTN2542 is not present in df2 but present in DF then filter out the whole row and save as xlsx file

Note: weather any column can be lower case or upper . i mean it should also take care of upper case and lower case

```
df <- data.frame(ID =c("DEV2962","KTN2252","ITI2624","DEV2698","HRT2921","","KTN2624","ANA2548","ITI2535","DEV2732","HRT2837","ERV2951","KTN2542","ANA2813","ITI2210","KTN2542"),
                 city=c("DEL","mum","MUM","DEL","del","MUM","DEL","del","MUM","mum","mum","mum","mum","DEL","DEL","mum"),
                 Name= c("dev,akash","singh,rahul","lal,ram","singh,nkunj","garg,prabal","ali,sanu","singh,kunal","tomar,lakhan","thakur,praveen","ali,sarman","khan,zuber","singh,giriraj","sharma,lokesh","pawar,pooja","sharma,nikita","shivam"))


df2 <- data.frame(ID =c("DEV2962","KTN2251","ANA2719","ITI2624","DEV2698","HRT2923","","KTN2624","ANA2548","ITI2535","DEV2732","HRT2837","ERV2951","KTN2542","ANA2813","ITI2210"),
                  city=c("DEL","mum","DEL","MUM","DEL","del","MUM","DEL","del","MUM","mum","mum","mum","mum","DEL","DEL"),
                  Name= c("dev,akash","singh,rahul","abbas,salman","lal","singh,nkunj","garg","ali,sanu","singh,kunal","tomar,lakhan","thakur,praveen","ali,sarman","khan,zuber","singh,giriraj","sharma,lokesh","pawar,pooja","sharma,nikita"))
```

the output i want to save in excel file as "records not in df"

[image]

in second sheet , list of records output "records not in df2"

[image]

Comment: Do you want to match only by `ID` ? Something like `dplyr::anti_join(df, df2, by = 'ID')` ?

Comment: yes, on the basis of ID , but meanwhile also want to to check if names are same for both ID in df and df2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `anti_join` from `dplyr`

```r
df <- data.frame(ID =c("DEV2962","KTN2252","ITI2624","DEV2698","HRT2921","","KTN2624","ANA2548","ITI2535","DEV2732","HRT2837","ERV2951","KTN2542","ANA2813","ITI2210","KTN2542"),
                 city=c("DEL","mum","MUM","DEL","del","MUM","DEL","del","MUM","mum","mum","mum","mum","DEL","DEL","mum"),
                 Name= c("dev,akash","singh,rahul","lal,ram","singh,nkunj","garg,prabal","ali,sanu","singh,kunal","tomar,lakhan","thakur,praveen","ali,sarman","khan,zuber","singh,giriraj","sharma,lokesh","pawar,pooja","sharma,nikita","shivam"))


df2 <- data.frame(ID =c("DEV2962","KTN2251","ANA2719","ITI2624","DEV2698","HRT2923","","KTN2624","ANA2548","ITI2535","DEV2732","HRT2837","ERV2951","KTN2542","ANA2813","ITI2210"),
                  city=c("DEL","mum","DEL","MUM","DEL","del","MUM","DEL","del","MUM","mum","mum","mum","mum","DEL","DEL"),
                  Name= c("dev,akash","singh,rahul","abbas,salman","lal","singh,nkunj","garg","ali,sanu","singh,kunal","tomar,lakhan","thakur,praveen","ali,sarman","khan,zuber","singh,giriraj","sharma,lokesh","pawar,pooja","sharma,nikita"))

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
anti_join(df2, df)
#> Joining, by = c("ID", "city", "Name")
#>        ID city         Name
#> 1 KTN2251  mum  singh,rahul
#> 2 ANA2719  DEL abbas,salman
#> 3 ITI2624  MUM          lal
#> 4 HRT2923  del         garg

anti_join(df, df2)
#> Joining, by = c("ID", "city", "Name")
#>        ID city        Name
#> 1 KTN2252  mum singh,rahul
#> 2 ITI2624  MUM     lal,ram
#> 3 HRT2921  del garg,prabal
#> 4 KTN2542  mum      shivam
```

If you need to join on the basis of a few columns (and not all columns instead) use `by` argument.